# what is the order of growth of this code segment?Explain little bit

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i*i < N; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j*j < 4*N; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < N*N; k++){
                sum++;
        }
    }
}
```

i know the order of growth of this code segment is N^3.But i need proper explain for this.

Comment: Like simply counting operations? From the outer loop to the inner one. `sqrt(N)*sqrt(N)*N^2 --> N^3`

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The most important thing to mention is that **the counters are independent**. Which is not the case in the other question. **Only then it is possible to just multiply the results**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the order of growth of this code segment is N^3

Yes, you're right.

The total number of execution is `sqrt(N) * sqrt(4 * N) * (N^2)` which is -

```
sqrt(N) * sqrt(4 * N) * (N^2)
=> 2 * sqrt(N) * sqrt(N) * (N^2)
=> 2 * N * (N^2)
=> 2 * (N^3)
=> O(N^3)
```

Comment: It is always the same... I answered first and give even more detailed explanation why you can just multiply, but the later answer gets acccepted and more upvotes, it's ridiculous.

Comment: Hi @maraca, I didn't notice your answer until I posted my answer, It was almost in several seconds difference, not even minute. And these things happen with me a lot of times, its really frustrating. I am upvoting your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse the loops step by step, because the counters are independent of each other:

1. Outer loop: executed sqrt(n) times.
2. Middle loop: executed sqrt(4 * n) = 2 * sqrt(n) times.
3. Inner loop: executed n^2 times.
4. Multiply the results: sqrt(n) * 2 * sqrt(n) * n^2 = 2 * n^3.

Thus follows O(n^3).